# Grouping multiple documents in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, grouping

I am trying to create a golf leaderboard based on multiple rounds, which means that a player can have played 2 rounds with the same matchid. It is pretty simple if there is just one round, I do it like this:

```
db.roundScores.find( { "matchId": matchId } ).sort({"data.scoreTotals.toPar": 1});
```

But, if a match have more than one round, I am a little in the dark on how i group each player, add the scores for the rounds and then sort them?

I am walking down this way, but not sure if this is the right way?

```
var allRounds = db.rounds.find( { "matchId": matchId } );

var playerScores = [];
while( allRounds.hasNext() ) {

    var thisRound = allRounds.next();
    var allScores = db.roundScores.find( { "roundId": thisRound._id.$oid } );

    var i = 0;
    while( allScores.hasNext() ) {
        var thisScore = allScores.next();

        if(i > 0){

            // Should be updating the playerScores array finding the object for the player, But how???

        } else {

            // Creating a new object and adding it to the playerScores array //
            playerScores.push({
                "id":   thisScore.playerId,
                "toPar": thisScore.scoretotals.toPar,
                "points": thisScore.scoretotals.points
            });

        }

        i++;
    }

}
```

I really hope that someone can guide me in the right direction on this.

Thanks in advance :-)

------------ EDIT -----------

Here is examples on the documents

```
{"roundId": "8745362738", "playerId": "12653426518", "toPar": 3, "points": 27}
{"roundId": "8745362738", "playerId": "54354245566", "toPar": -1, "points": 31}
{"roundId": "7635452678", "playerId": "12653426518", "toPar": 1, "points": 29}
{"roundId": "7635452678", "playerId": "54354245566", "toPar": 2, "points": 23}
```

The result should be:

```
1 playerId 54354245566 toPar 1 points 10
2 playerId 12653426518 toPar 4 points 2
```

Comment: Can you please post an example of one (multiple even) of your documents and the expected result?

Comment: @dnickless I have updated my initial question with examples on documents and expected outcome.

Comment: Is it neccessary to use JS i guess this can be achieved in mongodb with $group aggregation. let me know thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something to get you going:

```
db.roundScores.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: "$playerId", // group by playerId
        toPar: { $sum: "$toPar" }, // sum up all scores
        points: { $sum: { $max: [ 0, { $subtract: [ "$points", 25 ] } ] } }, // sum up all points above 25
    }
}, {
    $sort: { "toPar": 1 } // sort by toPar ascending
}])
```

Comment: Exactly what i was trying to accomplish :-) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a additional question though. I have added a field in documents called "points". Is it possible, in the same aggregate, foreach document, to get points above 25 and sum them for each player? You can see the result I am looking for in the initial question. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Yes, that works, too. Please see my updated answer. Mind you, I think, you did the maths wrong. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can go with MongoDB aggregation for this. A sample code below

```
db.roundScores.aggregate({
$group: {
    _id: "$playerId", 
    toPar: { $sum: "$toPar" },
    {$sort:{"toPar":1}}
 }
})
```

This will work

Comment: Exactly what i was trying to accomplish :-) Thanks a lot!